# Trying to understand the purpose of getRange function

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on to trigger, however from line as  - the Spreadsheet.GetRange(2, 19, 15, 3) won't go through. Message that prevents me to run: 'Exception: The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for '.

```
function sendEmails2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Refund by Bank'), true);

  // Fetch the range of cells A2:O7
  var dataRange = spreadsheet.getRange(2, 20, 15, 3);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[19]; // 19th column
    var message = row[20]; // 21th column
    var emailSent = row[21]; // 20th column
    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(2 + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1os7Z4vsj4lwynuepZRZnScRBiqyiKuM-gsFg-dVecYw/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Your issue is you're using the method signatiure for `getRange()` of Class `Sheet` on the method `getRange()` for Class `Spreadsheet`.*

#### More Information:

Both [Class `Spreadsheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) and [Class `Sheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) have a method called `getRange()`.

As per the documentation for `Spreadsheet.getRange()`, there exists only `getRange(a1Notation)`:

> **`getRange(a1Notation)`:**
>
> Returns the range as specified in A1 notation or R1C1 notation.

And for `Sheet.getRange()` there exists `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`:

> **`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`**
>
> Returns the range with the top left cell at the given coordinates with the given number of rows and columns.

As your variable `spreadsheet` is defined by:

```js
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
```

It is actually an instance of the `Spreadsheet` class, not `Sheet`. Therefore, the notation you are using is not valid.

#### Code fix:

Change your `dataRange` definition from:

```js
var dataRange = spreadsheet.getRange(2, 20, 15, 3);
```

to:

```js
var dataRange = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 20, 5, 3);
```

#### References:

- [Class Spreadsheet | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)

  - [Method `getRange(a1Notation)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation)
- [Class Sheet | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

  - [Method `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Answer (score -1):

It returns the rows and columns in the range specified. the first 2 arguments are the starting row and column, followed 2 range limits. So with the first 2 parameters you specify the starting row and column and with the other two you specify how many rows and columns are In your range for example:

`getRange(1,A,3,c)` gets range 1-4 rows and and A-D columns

Comment: Thanks for super quick response. I wanted to start at #2 row and #19 column and then get range of 15 rows and 3 columns, but I still get same error message. Do I need to write in letter of column instead of number?

Comment: This is incorrect. You can't use letters in `getRange()`. You either have to use A1 notation like `getRange("A1:D4")`, or you have to specify the start row, end row, and number of columns and rows likt `getRange(1, 1, 4, 4)`.